# A join query for three tables!! for the given condtion below

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables Orders table and customers table and orderstatus table, both order and customer table have customerid as common field,and order and orderstatus have order_status_id as common field

customer table have firstname, lastname, phone and email address fields.

Now if I have to search/select the orders according to customer firstname and/or lastname and/or phone and/or email and/or orderid, then what should be a mysql format of join query so that I can combine all the three tables to get the results from orders table along with orderstatus from orderstatus table?

Comment: You got me all excited by the subject of your question! ;-)

Comment: You see thats called marketing/advertising/campaigning

Comment: I clicked on the title just to see if there was something super fun (clowns? circus?) in here. Guess not.

Comment: For that U have to go to meta.stackoverflow.com and ask them to provide new features in editor so that we can put some your favorite (clowns? circus?)

Comment: Its still not working.. as per solutions so i better thought of deleting it as that may result yours negative marking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just join the tables. No need for outer joins or anything according to your current data definition.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders o, customers c, orderstatus s
WHERE o.customerid = c.customerid
AND o.order_status_id = s.order_status_id
AND c.firstname = 'OM'
AND c.LASTNAME = 'The Eternity'
AND o.orderid = 752
AND ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would start with LEFT JOINING all three tables together to start.

Then; structure your where clause to have a line like this for each parameter (basically; only applying filters in the case that parameters are provided)

```
WHERE 
(@customerFirstName IS NULL OR @customerFirstName = customers.FirstName)
AND (@customerLastName IS NULL OR @customerLastName = customers.LastName)
etc...
```

Depending on the number of records you're expecting; or if performance is lacking; you might want to think about creating a table variable to hold a smaller subset of data.  (i.e. create a #customers table; and then only insert into that customers that match customer search criteria.  Then join that to your other two tables)

Let me know if i've misunderstood your question; or if you'd like any clarifications.

Comment: Yes I do Need for what you have understood by my question? From the above given condition I need data from order table and order status from orderstatus table

Comment: Hmm; not sure I follow; but if you join all three tables together; you can include the data from the order table and order status tables in your select clause.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT `orders`.* , 
 `orderstatus`.`description`,
 `customers`.`firstname`, `customers`.`lastname`, `customers`.`phone`,`customers`.`email`
FROM `orders`
LEFT JOIN `customers` ON `customers`.`id`=`orders`.`customerid`
LEFT JOIN `orderstatus` ON `orderstatus`.`orderid`=`orders`.`id`
WHERE `customers`.`lastname`='blogs'
```

I'm not sure of your orderstatus table.